# How to write a Clojure macro that mimics Ruby's %w operator

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to write my first ever macro in Clojure. I want to mimic Ruby's %w{} operator, which works like this:

```
irb(main):001:0> %w{one two three}
=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

I want to write a function similar in Clojure that returns a vector of words. Here is how it would look:

```
user=> (%w one two three)
=> ["one" "two" "three"]
```

I know this is something that cannot be defined as an ordinary function because the symbols would be evaluated before applying and we would see something like this:

```
user=> (%w one two three)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: one in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

Here is my attempt at a macro:

```
(defmacro %w [& words]
  (map str (vec words)))
```

But it doesn't work.

```
user=> (%w one two three)
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/eval801 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
```

Why is this happening?

**ANSWERS**

So the problem was that the macro actually returned the correct output, but then the repl tried to evaluate it and "one" is not a valid function.

Thanks to the answers below, here are two correct macros that solve this problem:

```
(defmacro %w-vec [& words]
  "returns a vector of word strings"
  (mapv str (vec words)))

(defmacro %w-list [& words]
  "returns a list of word strings"
  (cons 'list (map str words)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because after macro-expansion clojure tries to evaluate ("one" "two" "three"), inducing your error message

```
user=> (%w one two three)
ClassCastException java.lang.String ("one") cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn (interface for callable stuff)  user/eval801 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
```

now you could do that

```
(defmacro %w [& words]
  (mapv str (vec words)))
```

generating a vector

or that

```
(defmacro %w [& words]
  (cons 'list (mapv str (vec words))))
```

generating (list "one" "two" "three")

or with syntax quote

```
(defmacro %w [& words]
  `(list ~@(map str (vec words))))
```

Comment: Why is nobody commenting on the useless calls to `vec` in the question and in all the answers? `(map f (vec x))` is just `(map f x)`, and `(cons 'list (mapv str (vec words)))` is even worse: it should be ``(cons `list (map str words))``. Note also that it's quite important to use backquote rather than regular quote for `list` here, otherwise your macro will fail when in a scope where `list` doesn't refer to `clojure.core/list`, either because of `:refer-clojure` in the namespace, or because of a local named `list`.

Answer (score 2):

Macros can be thought of as regular functions that take unevaluated code (as data structures) and return new code (as data), which then gets evaluated.

Your macro is returning `("one" "two" "three")`, which will evaluate as a *call of the function* `"one"` with arguments `"two" "three"`.

Straightforward solutions would be to make your macro return either `(list "one" "two" "three")` or a vector `["one" "two" "three"]`.